# Finding the date/time a file appeared in a git branch

Tags: git

How is possible to get the date in which a file appeared for the first time in a branch.

Currently I'm using the following. The problem is that for merges it returns the creation date in the original branch instead of returning the date of the merge.

`$ git log --first-parent --format=%ct FILE`

Comment: I tried it out and it returns exactly merge commit time for me. Can you provide a simplified scenario of how your git history evolved?

Comment: @KL-7 Actually you are right. However I have an application using this that, on another environment, returns the creation time of the file in the original branch. Maybe it doesn't work with older versions of git?

Comment: I can confirm it returns the original branch creation time on me too

Comment: @Fabio, I'm using v1.7.10. Btw, try `--format="%H - %ct"` to see whether you get SHA of the merge commit or of the commit from the original branch. Btw, is it possible that at some point the original branch was merged into your current branch with fast-forward merge?

Comment: I can confirm that my command doesn't work on `1.7.3.1` but it does in `1.7.11.1`. If somebody wants to document it in an answer I'll pick it.

Comment: @KL-7 It was a fast forward merge (GitHub pull requests) and I wasn't able to test your code as I don't have access to the machine where the issue was present.

Comment: @Fabio, I believe GitHub does non-fast-forward merge when you merge a pull request through their web interface, so it doesn't explain the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this problem is fixed in version 1.7.9.1 https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.9.1.txt

Comment: Quote: "git log --first-parent $pathspec" did not stay on the first parent chain and veered into side branch from which the whole change to the specified paths came.